# Search on static data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search

Is there any JavaScript library which can perform search on custom data. Something like Lucene for Javascript.

The Search Engine should run in the browser.

Thanks!

jaaly

Comment: Should run where? In a browser, on a server, or embedded somewhere?

Comment: you want to create some kind of search engine, on the client side ? Can you provide us more details so we can maybe help you to find another way to do what you want

Comment: The Search Engine should run in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) does that nicely if you want it on tables/with UI, you'll need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for that but it's pure javascript anyway. Otherwise look at the range of other plugins available for jQuery I'm sure you'll find something suitable there!